# sort a list in a data frame pandas but not a row

Tags: python, pandas, list

the other day I asked a question to add a string in a pandas data frame: in short I needed to add to the beginning of the table that was then coming to form a string and I queued a list of floats to it, after that in the code I want to sort the list and use `df = df.sort_values('consumo', ascending=False)`. The sorting works fine only I can't do it with that string at the top as well, since the column at the end would be a string + float and therefore can't be sorted.

```
def CreateExcel(metric,consumo, consumoMensile, consumoannouale, writer):
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        'metricID': metric,
        'consumo' : consumo,
        'consumo mensile': consumoMensile,
        'consumo annuale': consumoannouale,
    })
    df = df.sort_values('consumo', ascending=False)
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="foglio1", startrow=1, header=False, index=False)
    workbook = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets["foglio1"]
    (max_row, max_col) = df.shape
    column_settings = [{"header":column} for column in df.columns]
    worksheet.add_table(0, 0, max_row, max_col - 1, {"columns":column_settings})
    worksheet.set_column(0, max_col - 1, 70)
```

I would like to be able to add the strings like this:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        'metricID': ["time frame:"]+metric,
        'consumo' : ["11-10 12-10"]+consumo,
        'consumo mensile': ["11-01 12-01"]+consumoMensile,
        'consumo annuale': ["01-01 12-31"]+consumoannouale,
    })
```

this is what I would like to see come out:

| metricID | consumo | consumo mensile | consumo annuale |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| time frame: | 11-10 12-10 | 11-01 12-01 | 01-01 12-31 |
| First | row | row | row |
| Second | row | row | row |

Comment: Please show a clear [mre] including: exactly what might the DataFrame contain beforehand? (The sample should be small enough that you can directly show the complete contents, but just complex enough that it lets you show the problem.) Exactly what should be the result after, according to what logic? (It should be simple enough that you can calculate and show the correct result by hand.) What do you get instead when you try your code, and how is it wrong?

Comment: (also, if the problem is purely about working with a DataFrame, then we should not have any code for reading or writing from Excel - instead, hard-code a little data in the program, and just get a DataFrame result. We would only want the reading/writing code if the question is about a problem in reading or writing - and in that case, the question should be about **only** that.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
new_row = pd.DataFrame({'metricID':'Data frame', 'consumo':'from:2022-12-01 00:00:00 to:2022-12-14 16:13:00'}, index=[0])
df = pd.concat([new_row,df.loc[:]]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

so the code eventually becomes:

```
def CreateExcel(metric,consumo, writer):
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        'metricID': metric,
        'consumo' : consumo,
    })
    df = df.sort_values('consumo', ascending=False)
    new_row = pd.DataFrame({'metricID':'Data frame', 'consumo':'from:2022-12-01 00:00:00 to:2022-12-14 16:13:00'}, index=[0])
    df = pd.concat([new_row,df.loc[:]]).reset_index(drop=True)
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="foglio1", startrow=1, header=False, index=False)
    workbook = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets["foglio1"]
    (max_row, max_col) = df.shape
    column_settings = [{"header":column} for column in df.columns]
    worksheet.add_table(0, 0, max_row, max_col - 1, {"columns":column_settings})
    worksheet.set_column(0, max_col - 1, 70)
```

thanks for the help